# How to access an Html Form using a normal Java Application?

Tags: java, html, io, streaming

how can I access an Html Form and its components, say the Wikipedia Search Pane, using a normal Java Application? And enter some keywords? How would one **usually** handle this task?

I already figured out that a combination (of URL, URLConnection and BufferedReader), called »chaining«, allows me to *read in* a file, like this:

```
URL oracle = new URL("http://de.selfhtml.org/index.htm");
URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
```

But this *does certainly not* allow me to *write to* this Html Page.
Although, I know about its structure now, and **could address its components**.
And I need to address the Search Pane component, as it is laying on one of Wikipedia's Servers.

Having, I don't know, an `HtmlComponentOutputStream` would be nice.
In such a way that, the only things left to do would be calling:

```
HtmlComponentOutputStream.setText( "Penguin" );
HtmlComponentOutputStream.sendHtmlMessage( HtmlMessage.ENTER );
```

Thanks for reading so far, I'm grateful for any advise about how one would **usually** do this in Java.

Comment: HttpUnit could help you for this kind of stuffs. Maybe someone else has a better alternative.

Comment: If all you want to do is Wikipedia search, you could simply construct a URL like `http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=Hello+World`

Comment: to traverse the DOM: for testing purposes, i'd use [selenium API](http://seleniumhq.org/), for tokenizing general documents, i'd choose a fast parser, such as [XPP](http://www.extreme.indiana.edu/xgws/xsoap/xpp/).

Comment: Yeah you are right! I forgot about that the wiki system »offers« you to search by constructing the URL. That's not what I intend to do. I need to address the Html components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to automate browser action using java. 
If yes you can use Selenium RC (Selenium Web-driver). Java library to automate html page.

here is the link-

http://seleniumhq.org/download/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you would *normally* do it, but I'd issue a post request and set the form fields as key-value pairs, i.e. the key would be the form field name and the value would be the field's value.

If you don't know the form fields you might just read the form and extract the input fields and the form's target action. Then use a post request again.

Comment: Do you know which the Java Object **in charge** of issuing post requests is? I didn't find any in the API.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a html parser such as the [Cobra project Html Parser](http://lobobrowser.org/cobra/java-html-parser.jsp).

The have a specific example of how to submit a form.

Comment: This looks good, is there something more close to the Standard Java API? Because this third party code and requires installation before use.